# Put all the associative array in one variable

Tags: php, associative-array

I have some associative array whose values are inserted from a while{}.

```
//some sql select
$comar=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //another sql countrow
    $rowdd=mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $postuid=$row[2];

$comar[$postuid]= $rowdd[count(idnum)];
$_SESSION['comar']=$comar;

}
```

But this code just displays the idnum for last postuid. How do i add it all to one variable and then put that in a session.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: What is `$comar`, `$rowdd`, etc? What are you attempting to put in *one variable*?

Comment: i am putting the values in an array..

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't set your session variable in the while loop
2. `count(idnum)`. This makes no sense. Is `idnum` a constant. If so your fetching the same row.
3. What do you mean another SQL countrow. You're trying to fetch a row for which you have alreay run a `fetch_array` on. This makes no sense, and is probably the root problem